# Javascript whitespace issue

Tags: javascript, whitespace

In my container `news-variety` I got 4 columns, I just want to take all column in to left and animate each column to write.

For that I use the CSS `left` property.

I wrote the function to get the no. of column, but it adds whites space and display wrongly, in my case I need the `i` value `0,1,2,3,4` but this function shows `0, 2, 4, 6, 8`.

Please help me to remove the whites space and get the `i` value to `0,1,2,3,4`.

This is my code :

```
var newsVariety = document.getElementById('news-variety');
if(newsVariety){
    var newsColums = newsVariety.childNodes;
    for(i=0;i<newsColums.length;i++){
        if(newsColums[i].className == "column") continue;
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your i values appear not to progress linearly because of the continue statement. If newsColumns[i].classname == 'column", then your alert(i) never gets called. Move it up a line and you'll see a linear progression. Ass for the rest, well, I've no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting whitespace (text) nodes in addition to elements. You *could* exclude the text nodes like this:

```
var newsVariety = document.getElementById('news-variety');
    if(newsVariety){
        var newsColums = newsVariety.childNodes;
        for(i=0;i<newsColums.length;i++){
            if(newsColums[i].className == "column") continue;
            if(newsColums[i].nodeType == 3) continue;
            alert(i);
        }
    }
```

but a better solution would be to use a function (getElementsByTagName) that only gives you elements in the first place, like this:

```
var newsVariety = document.getElementById('news-variety');
    if(newsVariety){
        var newsColums = newsVariety.getElementsByTagName('whatever-your-element-tag-is');
        for(i=0;i<newsColums.length;i++){
            if(newsColums[i].className == "column") continue;
            alert(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i use like this : var newsVariety = document.getElementById('news-variety');
    if(newsVariety){
        var newsColums = newsVariety.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
        for(i=0;i<newsColums.length;i++){
            if(newsColums[i].className == "column") continue;
            newsColums[i].style.left = (i*23) +'%';    
        }
    } but not work

Comment: if i remove this line "if(newsColums[i].className == "column") continue;" then it's works fine. what is wrong?

Comment: How does it not work? Also, are you sure you want to continue if className == "column"? Aren't the divs with "column" class the ones you actually want to change?

Comment: The continue statement means "skip all the lines after this one and go through the loop again". So you probably want to remove that "if" and "continue" section.

Comment: i want to change the div with colum class. as well column div have the siblings and childrens as divs. if i remove the class name then the animation will affect all divs right?

Comment: If you only want to affect the columns, then change from if(newsColums[i].className == "column") continue; to if(newsColums[i].className != "column") continue; - that is, you want to skip everything that does NOT have the column class.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that whitespace is represented in the DOM as text elements.

```
if (newsVariety) {
  var newsColums = newsVariety.childNodes;
    for (col = 0, i = 0; i < newsColums.length; i++) {
      if (newsColums[i].className == "column")
        continue;
        alert (col++);
     }
 }
```